# How to get rid of the Narrator cursor box?

Tags: windows

I'm completely fed up with this blue narrator cursor box. It sits in the dead centre of my screen, and six little icons flash in the middle.  It is interrupting my work, and prevents me from playing games, as it is ALWAYS there to hide a crucial part of the game.  I have trawled the help forums and tried some of the suggestions, however nothing works, and this annoying box seems to never go away.  I have had this problem for about a month how,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A screenshot showing us what you are talking about would go a long way towards making this question more clear. Right now we can only guess at the source of the program that is annoying you.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> to bring up the "Ease of Access" control panel.

In the left hand list select "Narrator", in Windows 10 1803 it is the 7th item in the list.

Under "Use Narrator" toggle the switch to "Off"

---

Alternatively, as mentioned in the control panel you open above, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will toggle Narrator on and off.